# Переадресация post запроса в php

Tags: php, html

Работаю с objective-c, php незачем было учить, но сейчас сильно понадобился, подскажите пожалуйста как переадресовать пост запрос, пример:

```
Есть пост запрос 
login=123456
password=qwerty
отправка на vk.com,
```

но сделать так, чтоб отправка была на мой сервер mydomain.ru, php принял запрос и перенаправил уже в vk.com, как правильно будет сделать? Если можно готовый код... Если можно конечно )

Comment: Нужно написать API, который с помощью curl будет это делать.

Comment: так все поняяятно))

Comment: я не понял вопрос, поясните пожалуйста (откуда отправили запрос, куда пришли данные, что будет перенаправлять, куда перенаправлять и что перенаправлять), может быть у меня есть решение...

Comment: Если хотите перехватывать пароли, то это делается совсем не так.

Answer (score 1):

Задавался подобным вопросом и в конечно итоге пришёл к мнению что перенаправлять пост это ошибка в построении php приложения. Но если задача специфичная, то вот небольшая наработка без кудряшек и изучения апи контактика:

```
route.php

<form action="http://vk.com/" name="myform">
  <?php foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) { ?>
     <input name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" type="hidden" />
  <?php } ?>
</form>
<script>
  document.forms["myform"].submit();
</script>
```